# REST URL error handling using the Play framework

Tags: java, json, model-view-controller, rest, playframework

Currently when I (or more importantly, a user) type in one of my rest functions into the URL, it works, with the 200 status code. But if you type a wrong one or mispell it, a 404 page is generated, with a 404 status code when looking at it through a REST client.

Instead of getting a 404 page when the bad URL is sent, I would instead like to display a dynamically generated JSON object.

How do I fix that error handling to do what I want, Is there a place where I can define what should be done during a particular status code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not very familiar with the Play Framework, but I was interested. This [discussion seemed at least similar to what you want](https://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/c671b28df11a24e9):

> Gaëtan Renaudeau
>
> ...
>
> You can customize errors pages
> depending of the http code error (404,
> 500,  403, ...) by editing
> app/views/errors/{code}.html files
> where {code} is you  http code.  If
> you are using other format than html
> (like xml, json) you can have
> 404.json , 404.xml, etc...

So, modify:

```
app/views/errors/404.type_of_response
```

Hopefully this at least points you in the right direction.